Computer keep shutting down even with battery available (Gnome/Fedora)
. Hello guys, I have been hacked and since my computer is having weird stuff and keep shutting down even with battery, it seems I have a bad power configuration setup.
I'm using fedora 39 / Gnome 45.3
Any help, thanks.

what is your question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Not a question, just a list of statements. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLlv_aZjHXc

It is highly unlikely that you have been hacked. Hackers want your computer to keep working so they can take advantage of it for other purposes.

. Yes sorry indeed, I just need to figure it out. Where are gnome power settings, there must be some sort of bad config. My computer always need to be plugged even with batterie, any help where I can find this systemd/gnome config file to restore usual settings ?
